# Load .properties file without restarting WebLogic server - ADF Application

Tags: java, web-applications, properties, weblogic, oracle-adf

Environment : ADF application running on WebLogic Server 11gR1 - JDeveloper 11.1.1.7

Can I update and load .properties file on application run-time without restarting my weblogic server? If so please suggest how I can proceed with this requirement.

Comment: Please show how are you readin the file. Is it a for a `ResourceBundle` or plain properties? There is allways a way...

Comment: We are reading file using ResourceBundle. But it would be fine if you provide solution for loading property file without server restart after editing in both ways. Thanks. @NikosParaskevopoulos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but still here it goes:

Create a method in some backing bean, callable only from an administration page. This method would look like:

```
public void clearResourceBundleCache() {
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ResourceBundle.clearCache(cl);
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
public void clearResourceBundleCache() {
    ResourceBundle.clearCache();
}
```

([See relevant docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#clearCache%28%29))

To use this you would have to (1) replace the .properties files you want to change in the file system of the server and (2) call this method.

More sofisticated solutions would involve the `ResourceBundle.Control` ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html)).